# Decrypt a file using an RSA key pair I created in PuttyGen

Tags: security, encryption, rsa, private-key

I created a public and private key pair in PuttyGen (RSA-2048) and gave the public key to a co-worker to encrypt a string.  It was ultimately encrypted by a Microsoft Azure service and then the encrypted string (encrypted using the public key) was returned to us.

I cannot for the life of me figure out how to easily decrypt this string, given that I have the encrypted string and private key.  I'm sure there's something I can run from command line, a Windows PowerShell or command line would be preferred.  But I'm just unsure what the best tool is for simply decrypting the encrypted string given that I have the private key.

I also installed GPG4win and ran Kleopatra, but haven't been able to figure out how to decrypt with that (if it's even possible).

Comment: I'm seeing either openssl command line tool or gpg command line tool might be my best bet, am I on the right track?

Comment: yes likely, but the most important thing to determine at the second is the encryption algorithm used. the cipherstring is the result of the algorithm being run on the input string using the keys, so you need both the keys and software that can run that specific algorithm, whichever it is.

Comment: "a Microsoft Azure service" what service?